Shower handle fixture won’t come off
We can't seem to remove the shower handle. We got the knob off (it was threaded), but now the backing behind the knob won’t come off. Every video I find shows the plate should slide right off, but it won’t work. Any thoughts from here? My thinking is it might be so old that it’s corroded. I don’t see any other screw to take out.


There might be just caulking/sealer holding it to the wall.  Might need a razor blade/thin sharp knife to run behind it.

Please add more photos if possible.  Unless someone recognizes this exact part, it won't be possible to figure it out from a single angle.

https://imgur.com/a/QhfrzhT Let me know if more angles would be useful. We have a bag of white vinegar to try and break up any possible corrosion on it.

Will the other knob come off?

We got it off. Think it was corroded so some vinegar was enough to slide it off. We will be replacing it.
